# Draw pixels on mouse event in webgl - Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call

Tags: javascript, glsl, buffer, webgl

I am learning webgl and trying to understand how to communicate mouse positioning events to the GPU.  My goal is to create a simple draw program, where a `mouseover` or `mousedown` event on the webgl canvas will color the pixel at that position.  I am aware this is easier with 2d canvas, but the point is to learn about communicating between JS and GPU via buffers and uniforms.

My idea is that on every mousemove, to create a new buffer, bind it, set the data, and drawArrays.  (I chose this path as opposed to modifying an existing buffer based on advice in [(WebGL) How to add vertices to an already initialized vertex buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784580/webgl-how-to-add-vertices-to-an-already-initialized-vertex-buffer).  Some simple code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const gl = getGlContext('canvas', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true }); 

// simple util to compile and attach shaders
const { program } = setup(gl, vert1, frag1); 

gl.useProgram(program);

// Initialize placeholder buffer buffer - without this,
// webgl says there is no buffer attached, even though I 
// create and attach another buffer later?
const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
const resolutionUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_resolution');

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// set the resolution
gl.uniform2f(resolutionUniformLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const x = e.x - canvas.offsetLeft + 1;
    const y = e.y - canvas.offsetTop + 1;

    const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([x, y]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.vertexAttrib2f(positionAttributeLocation, x, y);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 3);
});
```

When I run this code, and mouse into the canvas, the canvas goes blank and I get the error:

> Vertex buffer is not big enough for the draw call

Clearly I am not understanding how to set up my buffers and buffer data.  My expectations were that a small buffer of length 2 is all that is needed to capture a single [x,y] coordinate.  Once the buffer is bound and the vertex attribute for position is set in the GPU, the draw call should draw that pixel coordinate in the color set in the fragment shader. What is wrong with my event listener that my code is not giving the expected behavior?

**Appendix:**

For reference, my shaders are very simple:

```c
// vertex shader
// Some extra code here to convert pixels to clip space within the shader,
// as opposed to within the javascript code

attribute vec2 a_position;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
  // convert the position from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
  vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

  // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
  vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

  // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clip space)
  vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

  gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

```
// fragment shader

precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,1,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple things wrong with your code.

1. Your `drawArrays` call specifies `3` indices, despite you only having a single 2D point in your buffer, the correct number of indices would be `1`.
2. `vertexAttrib2f` sets a static value to an attribute that's being used when the attribute *array* is not enabled, what you want to use here is `vertexAttribPointer`.
3. On that note, the previous dummy buffer and attribute pointer setup is redundant as it's not being used.

Effectively you can do this specific example of yours (plotting an individual pixel) without any buffers by just calling:

```js
gl.vertexAttrib2f(positionAttributeLocation, x, y);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
```

So your code would become:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true }); 

// simple util to compile and attach shaders
const program = setup(gl, vert1.textContent, frag1.textContent); 

gl.useProgram(program);

// disable position attribute
const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'a_position');
gl.disableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

// set the resolution
const resolutionUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'u_resolution');
gl.uniform2f(resolutionUniformLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const br = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.clientX - br.left;
    const y = br.height - (e.clientY - br.top);
    gl.vertexAttrib2f(positionAttributeLocation, x, y);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
});

function setup(ctx, vert, frag) {
  const vs = ctx.createShader(ctx.VERTEX_SHADER);
  ctx.shaderSource(vs, vert);
  ctx.compileShader(vs);

  const fs = ctx.createShader(ctx.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  ctx.shaderSource(fs, frag);
  ctx.compileShader(fs);

  const program = ctx.createProgram();
  ctx.attachShader(program, vs);
  ctx.attachShader(program, fs);
  ctx.linkProgram(program);
  console.log(ctx.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  return program;
}
```

```css
canvas { background: #efe; }
```

```html
<script id="vert1" type="x-vertex-shader">
// Some extra code here to convert pixels to clip space within the shader,
// as opposed to within the javascript code

attribute vec2 a_position;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;

void main() {
  // convert the position from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
  vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

  // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
  vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

  // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clip space)
  vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

  gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace, 0.0, 1.0);
}
</script>
<script id="frag1" type="x-fragment-shader">
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,1,1);
}
</script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

If you decide to still use buffers (when you need an arbitrary number of points / attributes) you should reuse a single buffer rather than manually allocating and setting up new buffers with every event.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If `vertexAttrib2f` simply sets a value to an attribute in the shader, then I see why I don't even need a buffer.  But if I remove all references to `createBuffer` and `bindBuffer`, I get `drawArrays: no buffer is bound to enabled attribute`.  My undertanding was that binding a buffer was the way to send data to the GPU.  Is that correct? Would you be willing to take a look at this [codesandbox playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-issues-with-drawing-ler3tx?file=/src/index.ts) demonstrating the issue and be a bit more specific about what I need to change in the code?

Comment: I clarified #2 in my answer as it was a bit misleading, you can think of [`vertexAttrib*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttrib) as setting a default value that's being used when there's no corrosponding attribute *array* bound (via a buffer). So to use the value set via `vertexAttrib` you'd not `enableVertexAttribArray` (or explicitly `disableVertexAttribArray`) of that attribute.

Comment: Generally speaking you can "send data to the GPU" via various means: buffers, textures, uniforms and attribute values (sorted descending in amount of data you can send).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, the statement `you can "send data to the GPU" via various means: buffers, textures, uniforms and attribute values (sorted descending in amount of data you can send)` explains it better than most of the webgl tutorials I've read.  I didn't know you would need to `disableVertexAttribArray` if you never enabled it in the first place. I tried your code, but that doesn't seem to work either - on mouseover, the canvas just dies silently (no errors or warnings) [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-issues-with-drawing-2-yx5c8h?file=/src/index.ts).  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm that seems like a browser bug, when you comment out `disableVertexAttribArray` the code works as expected (well, the math to plot below the cursor is wrong but it plots).
I've edited the example.

Comment: Note that attribute 0 (in your case "position") has a [special place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20308503/978057) in the opengl / webgl world, hence I suggested to explicitly set its state.

Comment: Sorry to keep at this, but unfortunately I still can't seem to get that to work.  With or without `disableVertexAttribArray`, mousing into the canvas clears it and nothing is drawn.  Were you able to get this functioning in a codesandbox?  If so, can you post a link?  I have tried this in codesandbox, as well as with a simple self-served version with webpack, and they behave identically.  I appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: Yeah it works for me, turns out it's codesandbox that doesn't properly work, for me it crashes when freshly loaded but starts working once it hotreloads the code after a change, so it's not at all related to disabling the vertex attribute array.

Comment: I've added an executable snippet here that works for me.

Comment: Your code makes sense and your snippet works. But the fact that webpack or parcel causes it to crash makes no sense to me.  I have created another question [WebGL canvas crashes when using webpack to bundle resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76519111/webgl-canvas-crashes-when-using-webpack-to-bundle-resources) about that problem, perhaps if you have time you cna give it a look.  Thank you!