# Trouble using mouse position in WebGL fragment shader

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, webgl, fragment-shader

Let's say I draw a texture to my WebGL canvas.  After the texture is drawn, I want to send the mouseover mouse position directly to the fragment shader, and perform some manipulation on that texture based on the mouse position.  My approach to this is to set a `uniform` in the fragment shader, and then on the mousemove event, I send the `x,y` position of the mouse to that uniform.  The JS code for this is relatively simple (could be optimized better):

```js
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const mouseCoordUniformLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(
        program,
        'u_mouseCoord'
    );

    const br = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = e.clientX - br.left;
    const y = br.height - (e.clientY - br.top) - 10;

    const position = new Float32Array(2);

    position[0] = x;
    position[1] = y;

    gl.uniform2f(mouseCoordUniformLocation, x, y);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
});
```

Within my fragment shader, I am attempting to use the uniform `u_mouseCoord` in deciding what color to paint the pixel.  For simplicity in this question, the rule is this - if the pixel position x and y are less than that of the mouse position, the pixel should be painted white.  Otherwise, it should be painted the pixel color of the canvas at that position.  (In real life my shader will have more interesting interactions between the texture and the mouse position.):

```c
// frag.glsl

precision mediump float;

// our textures
uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform vec2 u_textureSize;
uniform vec2 u_mouseCoord;

// the texCoord passed from the vert shader
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
  vec4 c = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
  vec4 white = vec4(1.0, 1.0 ,1.0, 1.0);

  float resolution = 512.0; // should be getting this as var from vertex shader

  if ((gl_FragCoord.x / resolution) < (u_mouseCoord.x / resolution)) {
    gl_FragColor = white;
  } else {
      gl_FragColor = c;
  }
}
```

My vertex shader is really pretty simple, it just does some transformations from pixels to clip space:

```c
// vert.glsl

attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
  // convert the position from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
  vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

  // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
  vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

  // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clip space)
  vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

  // pass the texCoord and mouseCoord to the fragment shader
  // The GPU will interpolate this value between points
  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;

  gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
}
```

There are some texture-related variables here.  For completeness, there is an appendix at the end of this question to show what I am doing with them.

When mousing over my canvas, nothing happens.  I am not sure why.  I had some success sending the mouse position to the shaders in the question [WebGL canvas crashes on mousemove, only when using webpack to bundle resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76519111/webgl-canvas-crashes-on-mousemove-only-when-using-webpack-to-bundle-resources), but this scenario is a bit different.  What am I doing wrong?  Is it wrong to try to send a `uniform` value directly from JS to the fragment shader (as opposed to sending it to the vertex shader, and then from there, to the fragment shader)?  I feel like my code is close, but the `u_mouseCoord` is not registering properly in the fragment shader on `mousemove`.

### [Here is a working codesandbox demonstrating the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-mouseposition-in-texture-yy77j9?file=/src/frag.ts).

#### Appendix

I want to be able to achieve the above behavior, with a texture that is a combination of several textures.  That may be TMI for the purposes of this question, but maybe something I'm doing with my textures is impacting my desired behavior.  Here is the setup to grab a few images, render them to textures, render them to a framebuffer, render the framebuffer to another (composite) texture, then render the composite texture to the canvas:

```js
import { getGlContext, setup } from "./utils";
import { verShadeText } from "./vert";
import { fragShaderText } from "./frag";
import topleft from "./tiles/253-1798.png";
import topright from "./tiles/252-1798.png";
import bottomleft from "./tiles/253-1799.png";
import bottomright from "./tiles/252-1799.png";
import "./styles.css";

// Fills the buffer with the values that define a rectangle.
export function setRectangle(
  gl: WebGLRenderingContext,
  x: number,
  y: number,
  width: number,
  height: number
) {
  const x1 = x,
    x2 = x + width,
    y1 = y,
    y2 = y + height;

  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    // prettier-ignore
    new Float32Array([
      x1, y1, 
      x2, y1, 
      x1, y2, 
      x1, y2, 
      x2, y1, 
      x2, y2]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );
}

export const gl = getGlContext();
export const { program } = setup(gl, verShadeText, fragShaderText);

interface Tile {
  path: string;
  position: { x: number; y: number };
}

export function main() {
  const tiles: Tile[] = [
    {
      path: topleft,
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 }
    },
    {
      path: topright,
      position: { x: 256, y: 0 }
    },
    {
      path: bottomleft,
      position: { x: 0, y: 256 }
    },
    {
      path: bottomright,
      position: { x: 256, y: 256 }
    }
  ];

  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  canvas.height = 256 * 2;
  canvas.width = 256 * 2;

  // For each tile image
  tiles.forEach((tile, i) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    image.onload = () => render(image, i, tile);
    image.src = tile.path;
  });
}

/**
 * When the image loads, run the following code to bring into the gl context
 */
function render(tileImage: HTMLImageElement, i: number, tile: Tile) {
  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var texcoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");

  // Create a buffer to put three 2d clip space points in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

  // Bind it to ARRAY_BUFFER (think of it as ARRAY_BUFFER = positionBuffer)
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  // Set a rectangle the same size as the image.
  setRectangle(
    gl,
    tile.position.x,
    tile.position.y,
    tileImage.width,
    tileImage.height
  );

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

  gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    // prettier-ignore
    new Float32Array([
            0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        ]),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
  );

  // Create a texture and bing it to the gl context
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

  // Upload the tile image to the texture
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    tileImage
  );

  // lookup uniforms
  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  var textureSizeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_textureSize");

  // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Turn on the position attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

  // Bind the position buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
  var size = 2; // 2 components per iteration
  var type = gl.FLOAT; // the data is 32bit floats
  var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
  var stride = 0; // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
  var offset = 0; // start at the beginning of the buffer
  // prettier-ignore
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // Turn on the texcoord attribute
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLocation);

  // bind the texcoord buffer.
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);

  // prettier-ignore
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
       texcoordLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // set the resolution
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  // set the size of the image
  gl.uniform2f(textureSizeLocation, 256, 256);

  // Draw the rectangle.
  var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
  var count = 6;
  gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}

main();
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 - my premise is that the texture objects are created just once (when the image loads) - then once the textures are attached, to manipulate them using the mousecoord, then redraw.  Is my premise wrong?  Forgive me if that is totally wrong, I'm new to webgl

Comment: @Rabbid76 in the last line of the `addEventListener` callback - the first codeblock in the question

Comment: `gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);` draws one single point, but nothing else. You can see the single white dot at the bottom left.

Answer (score 2):

You need to redraw the entire scene instead of just drawing a single point when the mouse position has changed, in the 'mousemove' event listener:

<s>`gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, 1);`</s>

```js
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Note, however, that only a single tile is redrawn in the process. I suggest to separate the part that creates the buffers and textures and the part that draws the tiles. Create a function that draws all the tiles and call it in the event listener.

Comment: Ahhhh, this makes sense.  Now, to make matters more complicated, as I said, I am patching together several images using several textures.  This solution seems to only apply the white to the last-added texture: [see this modified sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/webgl-mouseposition-in-texture-fix-option-1-fcp92y?file=/src/frag.ts).  Why is this?  How do I apply this logic to the composite texture / canvas as a whole?

Comment: @SethLutske I suggest to separate the part that creates the buffers and textures and the part that draws the tiles. Create a function that draws all the tiles and call it in the event listener. Of course I could write the code for you, but I usually get paid well for writing code and I think you got the idea and can do it yourself.